# MATLAB: Bar plot with varying colors based on magnitude of scale

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to plot a bar plot with color of bars changes based on magnitude of scale. I wonder if some one can point me out how to do so. Thanks,

[image: Bar plot with varying color]

Comment: the bars here are the same magnitude yet their color changes not the same way. what does it mean, and do you want that or something like this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/examples/graphics2/Color3DBarsByHeightExample_02.png

Comment: I would suggest building something with `pcolor` ... but your question lacks sooo many things to be answered. Why don't you give some sample data, and read [ask] and how to produce an [mcve].

Comment: yes, something similar to comment 1 but its in 3D, I want something in 2D with shades in the bar vary with magnitude of the data.  I also checked with this post: http://gadgetsytecnologia.com/3850f0bb1a497f4e1/matlab-bar-graph-fill-bars-with-different-colours-depending-on-sign-magnitude.html  but the example is not working. I am not getting any shades based on magnitude of as shown in the post. Any help?